# Problem rendering a Flutter TextFormBloc not rendering

Tags: forms, flutter, rendering, flutter-layout

I am using a TextFieldBlocBuilder in my UI.  I have been troubleshooting this for a while, but can’t figure out “why” a textfieldbloc is not appearing in my app.  I have surrounded it with simple Text and these two text fields appear, but the textfieldbloc does not.  I’m including a snippet of the code and would appreciate anyone who can tell me why or point me in the direction of things to look at…I’m stumped. (Also,  I’ve confirmed that the field I am populating the textfieldbloc with actually has a value.)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Card(
     color: Colors.blue[100],
     margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
         Row(
           // Row 1
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
           children: <Widget>[
             Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
               child: Text(
                 'Ingredient #${ingredientIndex + 1}',
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
               ),
             ),
             IconButton(
               icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
               onPressed: onRemoveIngredient,
             ),
           ],
         ),
         // Ingredient Attributes
         new Column(
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
           children: [
             Card(
                 //color: Colors.grey[100],
                 color: Colors.purple,
                 child: Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                     child: Column(
                         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Text("Yo"),
                           TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                             maxLength: 30,
                             maxLines: 1,
                             textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                             textFieldBloc:
                                ingredientField.ingredientName,
                             decoration: InputDecoration(
                               labelText: 'Ingredient Name',
                             ),
                           ),
                            Text("Yo-2"),
                         ]))),
           ],
         ),
       ]),
     ));
}
}
```

Here is the BlocBuilder code:

```
                        // Ingredient Card Start
                        BlocBuilder<ListFieldBloc<IngredientFieldBloc>,
                            ListFieldBlocState<IngredientFieldBloc>>(
                          bloc: formBloc.ingredients,
                          builder: (context, state) {
                            if (state.fieldBlocs.isNotEmpty) {
                              return
                                  // Constrained Box Start
                                  ConstrainedBox(
                                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                          maxHeight: 800,
                                          minHeight: 56.0,
                                          maxWidth: 800),
                                      child:
                                          // Constrained Box End
                                          ListView.builder(
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        physics:
                                            const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                        itemCount: state.fieldBlocs.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                          return IngredientCard(
                                            ingredientIndex: i,
                                            ingredientField:
                                                state.fieldBlocs[i],
                                            onRemoveIngredient: () =>
                                                formBloc.removeIngredient(i),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      )

                                      );
                            } else {
                              logger.d("_RecipeUpdate:xxx - state.fieldBlocks is empty");
                            }
                            return Container();
                          },
                        ),
```

This is what renders in the app for this widget (I’m expecting the textFieldBloc to appear between the “Yo” and Yo-2"):  [app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RitsS.png)

Comment: can you share the code for  TextFieldBlocBuilder?

Comment: Blockbuilder code was added above.

Comment: What does your builder returns `if (state.fieldBlocs.isNotEmpty)` this condition is not met?I think your `state.fieldBlocs` is empty.

Comment: I apologize....the copy paste of my code left out the else condition for the "if (state.fieldBlocs.isNotEmpty)".  I added it back in the code block above.  Also, it's not falling through on that condition because it is actually calling my "IngredientCard" widget....that is what is rendered in the screenshot I shared.  The text fields that are rendered surround the TextFieldBlocBuilder.  They are rendered, but the TextFieldBlocBuilder is not.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda stale, however anyone having the same issue can try the  solution on this [github issue](https://github.com/GiancarloCode/form_bloc/issues/237) out